# Heavy load (100% ni) and CPU load average is 42.61, 42.24, 42.23

Tags: linux, centos6, node.js

Machine: 8 Core processor with Centos 6.7

[top command result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5nGe.jpg)

I am using node.js, PHP-FPM, NGINX, Redis, MongoDB.

I have checked with stopping all services created my me and PHP-FPM, NGINX, Redis, MongoDB processes but still getting 100%ni and 41% load average.

my node.js code sending files to another server using htpp request.

How can I check which process is getting more CPU and why?

Comment: Run something like `ps -e -opcpu=,cmd= | sort -rn` and look at the output near the top to find processes using most CPU.

Comment: Also, sustained load average higher than the number of CPUs (`grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`) can be a sign of improper configuration. May be one or more of your applications are spawning too many threads as determined by their configuration.

Comment: 100%ni doesn't tell much. Pls post output of `top`

Comment: @user1700494 Follow the provided link [http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5nGe.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any further information, it is hard to say.

I'd guess you just have too much IO which is a common problem when databases are not configured correctly.

You can use `iotop` to see which processes use most IO and use `iostat` to see which partition has how much IO utilization.

Comment: Hi @steve,  I am using connection pool for mongodb and redis to connect with node.js and http load is lite (not more traffic).    And using Haraka for mail server. As per iotop haraka is using more IO. Can you help me how to reduce IO or should we increase resource?

Comment: We are using SSD and `iotop` is getting `Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s
`